# Remove parenthesis brackets-( and ) from string in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, string, replace

I have a string which contains characters `(` and `)`. I want to replace those characters with `""`.

I tried using

```
str.replace(/(|)/g,"")
```

And

```
str.replace(/'('|')'/g,"")
```

But they are not working

Answer (score 2):

As the characters `(` and `)` has special meaning in RegEx([*capturing groups*](http://www.regular-expressions.info/refcapture.html)), they need to be escaped by preceding with backslash to match the brackets literally.

```
str.replace(/\(|\)/g, "")
             ^  ^
```

```js
var str = 'Lorem ipsum dolor (sit) amet, consectetur (adipisicing) elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad (minim) veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure (dolor) in reprehenderit in (voluptate) velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in (culpa) qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.';

str = str.replace(/\(|\)/g, '');
document.body.innerHTML = str;
```

You can also use parenthesis inside character class `[()]`, where `(` and `)` are treated as literals.

```
str.replace(/[()]/g, '');
```

```js
var str = 'Lorem ipsum dolor (sit) amet, consectetur (adipisicing) elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad (minim) veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure (dolor) in reprehenderit in (voluptate) velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in (culpa) qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.';

str = str.replace(/[()]/g, '');

console.log(str);
document.body.innerHTML = str;
```

Answer (score 2):

Because you are using regular expressions the `()` characters are special characters.

You can however, put them in a character group, where they do not need to be escaped.

```
str.replace(/[()]/g,"")
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape the `(` and `)` characters with a `\` character, like this:

```
str.replace(/(\(|\))/g, "");
```

Comment: What is the purpose of the enclosing `()`?

Comment: The `(\(|\))` part matches `(` OR `)`. It's confusing with the backslashes to escape the characters, here's the same thing without the backslashes - `((|))`, the outer parentheses are a wrapper for the OR statement, and the `|` is the OR. Written out, its saying `(` `OR` `)`.

Comment: I am nitpicking. What I am saying is that the regexp you propose is functionally identical to `/\(|\)/`.

Comment: True. I guess I've become accustomed to wrapping `OR` statements in `()`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape `(` and `)`:

```
str.replace(/\(|\)/g,"")
```